# How to get info after push to GitLab with gitpython

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab, gitpython

I'm using the [gitpython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) library to interact with GitLab. It works fine (push and create MR) except I can't find how to obtain a message (remote:) from GitLab after the push.

```
$ git push

Enumerating objects: 54, done.
Counting objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Writing objects: 100% (38/38), 31.09 KiB | 4.44 MiB/s, done.
Total 38 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: 
remote: View merge request for branch:
remote:   https://gitlab.my.company.com/project/repo/-/merge_requests/777
remote: 
To https://gitlab.my.company.com/project/repo.git
 * [new branch]        branch -> branch
```

Code used in GitPython:

```
if repo.is_dirty():
    repo.git.add(all=True)
    repo.git.commit(m="my commit")
    origin = clusters.remote()
    # res = origin.push(branch, o="merge_request.create")
    res = clusters.remotes.origin.push(branch, o="merge_request.create")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `message (remote:)`? Do you mean a commit message?

Comment: Message from gitlab with link to MR(shown in output)